# Script for connection with ssh then command once connected

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I need to write a script that connects to a remote server, then once connected, connects from there to another server, then changes directory.
The following of course does not work (it connects to first server then the script is halted, and resumed once disconnected):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo begin:
ssh  serv_1
ssh  serv_2
cd dir1

exit 0
```

What do I need to do ?
I read some posts with questions similar to mine, but I did not understand the answers.

Comment: If you want the second connection to happen from the first one, it needs to be run on that first server, not from your client.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to run all the commands above in one single script located on the client ?

Comment: Actually there is.  A simple solution would be to use input redirection but a better approach would be to make a script on the first server.

Comment: I would like to simply run one script from the client. What are the commands ?

Comment: @Donald Please update your post, and show us which script you wanna run ? from where to where ?

Comment: @arzyfex All is in the script above: if I type manually, I do: ssh name_of_serv1 then ssh name_of_serv2 then cd some_dir   that is all.

Comment: @Donald so you want to `ssh serv1` and run some command then `ssh serv2` and run some command in your script, right ?

Comment: @arzyfex No, I need to to things in the order: ssh serv1 then ssh serv2 then commands

Comment: @Donald If you don't wanna do anything after ssh, then what is the point in `ssh`ing to serv1 and serv2 ?

Comment: This is not the question. But I connect to a server used to handle connections of users, then I connect immediately to another one for computations. It is required to do it that way as serv2 is not directly accessible and serv1 is not to be used for computations.

Comment: Do you get any password or similar prompts in the process?

Comment: does `serv_1` have any kind of cluster job scheduling tools, like `pbs` or `slurm` or `torque`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is,

`ssh srv_1 'ssh srv_2 "command"'`

where command is whatever command you want to run.

It also works without the single quotes, but I like them to aid in understanding.

`ssh srv_1 ssh srv_2 "command"`

Using the quotes gives us some structure to work within, but as you can see, they're not fundamentally necessary.

This also works,

`ssh srv_1 ssh srv_2 command`

We can't tell from the information you've given us if this will work, or if the command will do anything, but the above syntax is the approach I would take.

If you have to start using variables or command substitution then it'll get more complex, more quickly and you'll need to be careful with quoting and escaping.

Here's an example of it working.

Neptune is my host machine.
Trinity is another server.
Matrix is the final server.

```
tony@neptune:~$ ssh trinity 'ssh matrix "hostname"'
matrix
```

So the command returns the hostname matrix, because it has executed on the server matrix.

NB: Changing a directory in this way will have absolutely no effect, directory changes are relevant only to the shell in which they're executed.

Here's what I mean,

```
tony@Neptune:~$ ssh trinity 'ssh matrix "cd /tmp"'
tony@Neptune:~$ ssh trinity 'ssh matrix "pwd"'
/home/tony
```

The second command shows the previous `cd` command has had no lasting effect.